# PHP Separate admin controllers CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

I have some basic controllers and admin controllers, I'm trying to separate them in folder to avoid things like this one:

controllers/user.php -> general users
controllers/a_user.php -> for admin users

I've read some things about route but couldn't find a way to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just copy them in their own folder and request them as needed (add the path to the URL in front of the controller name).

Comment: I'll add the admin folder inside controllers folder or outside it?

Comment: Create a subfolder inside controllers folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a subfolder inside controllers folder and place your admin controllers in there.